# What am I doing wrong with JQueryUI's tabs feature?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I feel really silly for asking this, but what am I doing wrong with http://www.wcarsucks.com? I followed their example exactly, no dice.

Comment: Get a jQuery UI Theme: http://themeroller.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working from this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and it looks like you just need to style your tabs, and to include the required css styles in your page.

```
<style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
     display: none;
}
</style>
```

aside from that, if you use something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and inspect your page, you will see that it appears to be working and applying the right css classes to elements.

Comment: Thanks. I always forget this. I feel silly for having to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem is that the stylesheet for jQuery UI isn't loaded.
If you inspect the DOM elements after the page is loaded, you see that all the required classes for the tab interface has been added.